# What is the source of the Four Dhamma Summaries?

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, sutta-reference

What is the source of the [Four Dhamma Summaries](https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/ChantingGuide/Section0013.html)?

From which sutta does it come from?

> 1. The world is swept away. It does not endure.
> 2. The world offers no shelter. There is no one in charge.
> 3. The world has nothing of its own. One has to pass on, leaving everything behind.
> 4. The world is insufficient, insatiable (*atitto*), a slave to craving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MN 82 Raṭṭhapāla Sutta](https://suttafriends.org/sutta/mn82/):

> ‘All beings are swept away toward old age and death. Therefore, the
> world is unstable.’ This is the first theme.
>
> ‘Life is insecure and everything is out of one’s control.’ This is the
> second theme.
>
> ‘We own nothing—we  must leave it all behind and pass on.’ This is the
> third theme.
>
> ‘Something is lacking in everybody’s life, no one is fully satisfied,
> beings are slaves of craving.’ This is the fourth theme.

One interesting thing to note, the same exact plotline is followed in the [story](https://www.wisdomlib.org/buddhism/book/the-great-chronicle-of-buddhas/d/doc364582.html) of another monk name Sudinna, a merchant's son.  The only difference is the ending; it doesn't end with the four points in question.  Instead the monk is persuaded to procreate with his ex-wife which results in admonishment from Buddha and company.